# На сколько правильно использовать throw для обработки пользовательских ошибок?

Tags: node.js, express

На сколько правильно использовать throw для обработки пользовательских ошибок? 
Ниже приведен рабочий код, но я не уверен, что он корректный стилестически. 
В случае если пользователь не найден в базе данных, генериться throw с текстом и кодом ошибки, который перехватывается на уровне catсh самой функции  из которой опять вызывается throw и далее идет логгирование и возрат сообщения об ошибке из функции в app.js.

```
async function login(req, res) {
  try {

    const db = req.app.db;

    params = { email: req.body.email, isDeleted: false }
    doc = await db.users.findOne(params);

    if (!doc) {
      const msg = `User ${req.body.email} not found.`;
      throw new Error(msg, 404);
    }

    const resultComparePassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, doc.password);

    if (!resultComparePassword) {
      const msg = 'Invalid password';
      throw new Error(msg, 401);
    };

    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        id: doc._id,
        email: doc.email,
        role: doc.role
      },
      process.env.JWT_KEY,
      {
        expiresIn: "1h"
      }
    );

    const msg = {
      token: token
    };
    return res.status(200).json(msg);

  } catch (ex) {
      throw new Error(ex);
  }
};
```

### Код app.js

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const error = new Error('Not Found');
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(err.stack);
    next(err);
});

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(error.status || 500);
    res.json({
        error: {
            code: error.code,
            message: error.message
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> На сколько правильно использовать throw для обработки пользовательских ошибок?

Конечно, генерирование исключений инструкцией `throw` — правильно и корректно. Используйте этот подход!

---

Но к вашему коду есть несколько замечаний.

> [Конструктор Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) создаёт объект ошибки. Экземпляры объекта Error
>   выбрасываются при возникновении ошибок во время выполнения. Объект
>   Error также может использоваться в качестве базового для
>   пользовательских исключений.
>
> new Error([message[, fileName[, lineNumber]]])

Не корректно генерить исключение так как это делаете вы `throw new Error(msg, 404)`. Второй аргумент нисколько не напоминает ожидаемый параметр `fileName`.

Тут вам нужен наследник класса `Error`, который будет знать о коде ошибки:

```
class HttpError extends Error {
  constructor(message, status) {
    super(message);
    this.status = status;
  }
}
...
throw new HttpError(msg, 404)
```

В ответах на вопрос [What's a good way to extend Error in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382107/whats-a-good-way-to-extend-error-in-javascript) вы сможете подобрать наиболее подходящий вам способ объявить ваш класс ошибки.

Кроме этого, вполне хорошим решением будет взять на npm готовый модуль, например [http-errors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-errors), в котором уже реализован функционал http-исключений.

И ещё одно замечание к коду: нет смысла заворачивать код в `try..catch` только для того чтобы в `catch` пробросить ошибку выше - это произойдёт само по себе.

Comment: Я заворачиваю весь код в try catch - для универсальности. Все остальные функции буду писать по аналогии. Мне не совсем понятно, как пользователю возвращать один текст ошибок (короткое сообщение), а в логах фиксировать полный текст сообщения.

Comment: в этом нет никакой универсальности, лишь накладные расходы. "Мне не совсем понятно, как пользователю возвращать один текст ошибок (короткое сообщение), а в логах фиксировать полный текст сообщения." - вариантов много: на месте написать вывод в лог console.error или добавить в HttpError атрибут и выводить его в обработчике ошибок в app.js

Comment: можно простой пример?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wY413maA имхо, это - самый нормальный подход. но можно сделать что-то вроде https://pastebin.com/mgXPiZEi (но этот вариант не нравится мне тем, что в нём неявно смешивается и обработка запроса, и бизнес-логика)

Comment: вот тут ещё описывается симпатичный хэлпер `handleError` https://dev.to/nedsoft/central-error-handling-in-express-3aej

Comment: Супер пример. Кстати он тоже использует try catch на уровне функции, но вместо заключительного throw использует next. Еще один вопрос по данной тематике - а как добавить в приведенном примере поддержку мультиязычных сообщений? Для каждого языка отправлять сообщение об ошибке на своем языке

Comment: мультиязычность я бы оставил client-side. на бэке делаем словарь ошибок, а на клиенте рулим показом на нужном языке